# Company repost job a day after informing me that HR will be contacting me to negotiate compensation package for the role

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I interviewed with the subordinate of a hiring manager which included some technical questions - I was told that I performed up to expectations. The next day, I received a call from the hiring manager informing me that they'd like to submit my profile to HR to commence negotiation of compensation.

During the call, the hiring manager remarked that many candidates have back out from an acceptance offer or demanded an obscene mark up in terms of agreed upon compensation package.

The following day I saw that the job has been posted.

What is the best way for me to deal with this professionally? Remember that I have yet to communicate with the HR directly on expectation of compensation.

Edit:
Got a call and the expected compensation I negotiated for.

Comment: Well, maybe they need two of you...

Comment: How big is the company? Large companies post similar job descriptions when posting some openings.

Comment: From the companies viewpoint, they haven't employed you yet or made an offer. They could just be keeping their pipeline of candidates full, in case you and they cannot come to an agreement. What they do with adverts is irrelevant for you; you're at the negotiating stage.

Comment: "they'd like to submit my profile to HR to commence negotiation of compensation" I'd like to pack my bag to commence pondering about buying ticket. The company might start talking with you but they won't pinhole themself to just your candidature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What is the best way for me to deal with this professionally?

Try to negotiate a fair compensation. If that fails, decline and move on to another opportunity.

There is absolutely no need to worry about the job being reposted. That is often standard procedure.

> the hiring manager remarked that many candidates have back out from an
> acceptance offer or demanded an obscene mark up in terms of agreed
> upon compensation package.

That is a bit odd. It's not at all clear what "an obscene mark up in terms of agreed upon compensation package" means. Perhaps the hiring manager is hinting why the job is being reposted - they haven't gotten an accepted offer yet. Or perhaps its a hint that applicants are asking for more than the company is willing to pay.

Comment: "It's not at all clear what "an obscene mark up in terms of agreed upon compensation package" means." I would assume that it means that someone negotiates a compensation package, agrees to an amount, gets the acceptance offer, then asks for significantly more than they agreed to.

Comment: Great inputs.

The role I applied to is a pretty hot role within tech so candidates are often left with better bargaining power as the supply at the 3-5 years mark is extremely short so bid war is real
@Acccumulation is spot on - hiring manager mentioned multiple candidates would ask for a base monthly of 7500 USD from 6000 USD a day after agreeing on compensation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere

what a difference the absence of "," makes! To be clear, an increment from 6000 USD to 7500 USD compensation on a monthly basis.

Answer (score 0):

The job being reposted isn’t something for you to deal with, professionally or otherwise. It might be a precaution in case you decide to back out at the last minute or maybe they just got the budget approved to hire someone else in the same position. Wait a few days for HR to get in touch. If you don’t hear anything, try giving them a call.